# MaterialApp home widget doesn't get rendered when Consumer triggers rebuild. NEEDS-PAINT

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm playing around with Flutter and while building the login flow I've stumbled upon an issue I couldn't figure out.
The main idea is that I'm using a provider for the Authentication details and this is exposing a getter saying if the user is authenticated or not. Based on this, I want to conditionally set the **home** widget to either be the Dashboard or the Welcome screen of the app. This technique is exactly the same one used in a udemy course by Maximilian Schwarzmüller.
[image]

Now, I've checked with debugger and after successfully setting the authentication, the home widget is not changed. In DevTools, I can see the DashboardScreen widget being added to the tree, but is not displayed on the screen. It has though a strange message with 'NEEDS-PAINT'.

[image]

Here's the DashboardScreen widget just for the information:
[image]

Is there something I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After successfully setting the authentication, are you calling `notifyListeners()` inside your `Auth` business logic ? The Consumer won't rebuild by itself until you do so.

Comment: Yes, It's called. When debugging, I also can see that build method is called, but in fact the widget is not displayed properly as you can see in the screenshot with DevTools, the DashboardScreen is there, but not showing on emulator.

Here's the difference, just before calling notifyListeners(): https://imgur.com/a/IaUj3qn

Comment: I didn't see you were using named routes. You might need to listen to the provider in the initState and push the named route from there.

Comment: Also, the widgets are stateless.